# tkinter progressbar does not work properly

Tags: python, tkinter, progress-bar

I am facing problem with tkinter progressbar.
Below is my code.

I am trying to show a progressbar (indeterminate mode) which the program is running a function. But it only appear after the function is completed, not before. How can this happen? The progressbar was started before the function('test') is executed..

Many thanks

below is the code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time

def progressbar(parent):
    global pb
    pb = Progressbar(parent, length=100, mode='indeterminate', maximum=100, value=50)
    pb.pack(padx=2, pady=2, expand=YES, fill=X)
    pb.start()


def test():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    return i

root = Tk()
progressbar(root)
test()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please paste the code here

Comment: please give your code here

Comment: added. sorry. i was putting it in a picture format

Comment: ```test()``` is called before ```root.mainloop()``` so it will appear only after ```test()``` has finished being executed

Comment: Alright... So is there any other way to have the progressbar being shown and run while the test() is  running?

Comment: `test()` has a call to `time.sleep()` and will freeze the code execution, and when code execution freezes, it does not reach `root.mainloop()`(until `test` is done executing), hence there is no window for you to see.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the `test()` function before the `mainloop()` as Sujay said.
You can solve this by creating some sort of a button, that when clicked on, the `test()` function will activate.